# 'The instance of entity type 'Cruise' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Выдает ошибку при выполнении кода указанного ниже

```
await _cruiseRepository.UpdateRangeAsync(existedCruises.Select(x =>
  new Cruise { Id = x.Id, StartDate = x.StartDate, EndDate = x.EndDate, ShipId = x.Ship.Id }));
```

Ошибка появляется из-за того, что я создаю новые экземпляры объекта Cruise, но я думал, что можно просто указать Id. Проблему я обошел путем нахождения сущности по id, но из-за этого мне приходится использовать UpdateAsync вместо UpdateRangeAsync в коде ниже. Вопрос в том, что мне кажется код ниже можно сделать более чистым-красивым и более производительным, только как лучше?

```
foreach(var existed in existedCruises)
{
   var entity = await _cruiseRepository.GetByIdAsync(existed.Id);
   entity.StartDate = existed.DateStart;
   entity.EndDate = existed.DateEnd;
   entity.ShipId = existed.Ship.Id;

   await _cruiseRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
}
```

Метод UpdateAsync выглядит так:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

UpdateRangeAsync выглядит аналогично

Comment: Просто не надо задавать `Id`. Убрать вот это: `Id = x.Id`.

Comment: Он поймет какой обновлять и не поменяет id после?

Comment: Он же просто создаст новую запись в таблице с другим Id, нет?

Comment: Ну так вы же и создаёте новую запись: `new Cruise `

Comment: Поэтому я стал находить сущность по id во второй части кода и у меня появился вопрос, как сделать это более качественно-красиво

Comment: Чтобы было качественно-красиво, нужно отказаться от EF - это фреймворк уныл. Рекомендую linq2db. Или по крайней мере следует использовать дополнения к EF, которые позволяют делать массовый Update.